# Is there a way to use multisampling with `GLKView` in iOS?

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0

Is there a way to use `GLKViewDrawableMultisample4X` property of `glkView`?

```
// It works! 
//glkView.drawableMultisample = GLKViewDrawableMultisampleNone;

// It doesn't work! Black screen! 
//glkView.drawableMultisample = GLKViewDrawableMultisample4X;
```

I googled it but there is no answer.

Xcode version: 7.1.1

Comment: How are you triggering the rendering?

Comment: @Dave, `captureOutput()` calls my render function. It's delegate by `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set `glkView.enableSetNeedsDisplay = 0;` I was getting weird behavior when I forgot to set it to 0 and was calling display directly, but only with multi-sampling enabled.

Comment: I tryed set this properties in Main.storyboard too. "setNeedsDisplay" and "Multisample", but got the same result. black screen..

Comment: When you have set enableSetNeedsDisplay to 0, and set drawableMultisample to GLKViewDrawableMultisampleNone. Does it display properly?

Comment: Yes, it displays properly in this case!